# Why "Revoke Priviliges" Command Doesn't Work in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to remove all priviliges of a user on a db, I executed the command below but it doesn't change anything. What is the problem?

```
revoke all on db.* from 'user'@'host';
```

Comment: What privileges did the user have before on the db in question and what priviliges does it have after?

Comment: @Shadow the user has all priviliges on a db for all tables. I want to revoke the _"all"_ and to set only _"select"_ privilige.

Comment: You probably need a `flush privileges;` after you do the revoke.